# Unable to Execute a Stored Procedure with Input and Output parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
sd varchar2(30);
v1 number(3,2);
v2 number(3,2);
b1 number(3,2);
b2 number(3,2);
b3 number(3,2);
b4 number(3,2);
b5 number(3,2);
b6 number(3,2);
b7 number(3,2);

begin
sd:='secondary education';
execute academics_data(sd,v1,v2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7);
dbms_output.put_line('values are: v1='||v1||' v2='||v2||' b1='||b1||' b2='||b2||' b3='||b3||' b4='||b4||' b5='||b5||' b6='||b6);
end;
```

I am trying to execute the above PLSQL block with a Stored Procedure. But the error is as follows.

> Error starting at line 1 in command: declare sd varchar2(30);  v1
>   number(3,2);  v2 number(3,2);  b1 number(3,2); b2 number(3,2);  b3
>   number(3,2); b4 number(3,2);  b5 number(3,2);  b6 number(3,2); b7
>   number(3,2);
>
> begin sd:='secondary education'; execute
>   academics_data(sd,v1,v2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7);
>   dbms_output.put_line('values are: v1='||v1||' v2='||v2||' b1='||b1||'
>   b2='||b2||' b3='||b3||' b4='||b4||' b5='||b5||' b6='||b6); end; Error
>   report: ORA-06550: line 15, column 9: PLS-00103: Encountered the
>   symbol "ACADEMICS_DATA" when expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; immediate The symbol ":=" was substituted for
>   "ACADEMICS_DATA" to continue.
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Yeah this works right. Thank You Aleksej!

Comment: Notice you didn't put `execute` in front of `dbms_output.put_line`. It's just another procedure (that happens to be provided by Oracle), so you call them the same way.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of the call is wrong. In a PL/SQL block you don't use the `execute` command - that's used at the SQL*Plus command line only. Rewrite your block as:

```
declare
  sd varchar2(30);
  v1 number(3,2);
  v2 number(3,2);
  b1 number(3,2);
  b2 number(3,2);
  b3 number(3,2);
  b4 number(3,2);
  b5 number(3,2);
  b6 number(3,2);
  b7 number(3,2);
begin
  sd:='secondary education';
  academics_data(sd,v1,v2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7);
  dbms_output.put_line('values are: v1='||v1||' v2='||v2||' b1='||b1||' b2='||b2||' b3='||b3||' b4='||b4||' b5='||b5||' b6='||b6);
end;
```

Best of luck.